# .click function doesn't work for class if more element have this class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This works fine:

```
$('.classname').click(function() {
  alert('');
});
<div class="classname">Click me!</div>
```

But this doesn't:

```
$('.classname').click(function() {
  alert('');
});
<div class="classname">Click me!</div>
<div class="classname">Click me!</div>
```

How can i fix this? Thanks for your help!
(The script in  tags, and the .click is in a document ready function)

Comment: That [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/k7U6G/). Are you adding the extra elements dynamically?

Comment: Your code is working, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/WsXBk/

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"?
Do you have any console errors? This code should work fine.

Comment: did you insert any node dynamically after page loaded, just as @JamesAllardice guessed? if so, please update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$('PARENTNODE').on('click', '.classname', function() {
  alert('');
});
<div class="classname">Click me!</div>
<div class="classname">Click me!</div>
```

The elements are added after your click handler is attached. By using .on() you enable it for future elements too.

Replace PARENTNODE with the parent you want to delegate to (eg. body)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.classname', function() {
      alert('');
    });
});
```

Refer http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: How is that going to make any difference? That's exactly what jQuery does behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: Refer answer here stackoverflow.com/questions/8601482/jquery-on-vs-click-methods

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to target elements that don't exist at the moment where .click is called.

You could wrap the whole jquery code between $(function() { your code here }); or move the javascript after the two <div>.

Comment: The OP says that it works with one div so this is unlikely to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that all the divs but the first one are added dynamically.

Use an event delegated approach:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.classname', function() {
        alert('');
    });
}),
```

Comment: The order of the arguments is wrong. You have to flip '.classname' and 'click'